Should I give up on trying to date her?
I've [30M] been talking with a girl [33F] for 6 months now. She is my coworker. We've not gone on any dates on account of her not having a baby sitter (2 young kids). We text or talk on the phone almost every day and she's the one that initiates the contact. About a month ago, she told me that she liked me but wanted to be just friends because she doesn't see how we could go on dates or do anything romantic and that she doesn't want me waiting around for her. We've continued talking even after this and she told me that she still has feelings for me (is it normal for friends to have romantic feelings for each other?). Fast forward to today where we were doing a gift exchange. We got each other some gifts and after we exchanged them, I hugged her then went in for a kiss and she gave me her cheek. I like her but now I'm wondering if I should give up pursuing anything with her but before I decide, I'd like some outside perspectives on my situation. Please let me know if there are any details you would like to know.
TLDR: a woman (and corworker) I like is giving me mixed signals and I would like to know if it's time to give up.

Hi Yudi, welcome to IPS. Unfortunately, as it stands, your post is off-topic, because you have to decide what you do, not random strangers on the internet. We can help with communicating with her maybe, not more though. Please take a minute for the [tour] and read [ask].

Without even reading this question, I know that this is oppinion-based.

It might help to check if others agree that she is giving ... mixed signals. Is it unclear that wanted to be just friends and she doesn't want me waiting around for her?

In my experience: If she wanted more, it would've by now. This gives me "you're the backup guy" vibes. My suggestion would be to move on, everyone should have someone who actually wants to be with you, without doubt.
